# How can I set default value to size type property of propertyygrid in c#?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a propertygrid that myclass is objectsource of it. In my class I define one item from Size type. How can I set default value in item attribute ?

Please see my code :

```
[CategoryAttribute("Information"), DefaultValue(Size(0, 0))]
public Size AndaazehPixel { get; set; }
```

my error : 'System.Drawing.Size' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "0, 0")]
public Size AndaazehPixel { get; set; }
```

Comment: This works because Size has a TypeConverter attribute on the class, if you need the sme for your own property types then you will need a TypeConverter attribute.